# StreamBuilder Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement a stream builder to display a String from a firebase document.
However I get the following error "The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type." on the 3rd line of the code. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

```
    StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _firestore.collection('data').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) { 
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const ErrorWidget();
            }
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final messages = snapshot.data!.docs;
              List<Text> messageWidget = [];
              for (var message in messages) {
                final messageText = message.get('email');
                final messageWidget = Text('$messageText');
              }
              return Column(
                children: messageWidget,
              );
            }
          },
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another return after and outside your second if statement. Because currently your streambuilder only returns on two conditions, either error or hasData. But what about everything else? For example waiting?

You can add `return CircularProgressindicator()` at the end, and it should work.

Comment: Amazing that compiles perfect! Thanks you so much. However now it doesn't display anything, not sure why..

Comment: You're welcome! Do you get any renderflex errors? If it's compiling that means either the text is white or your column is inside a listview or something. Change it from message widget to a fixed text and see what happens. Something for be displayed

Comment: Yep exactly! Thanks so much

Comment: You're most welcome, if it solved your problem, kindly consider marking it as the correct answer to your post, thanks!